# How to scan a string for an exact keyword match?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scanf

I'm scanning names and descriptions of different items in order to see if there are any keyword matches.

In the code below it will return things like 'googler' or 'applecobbler', when what I'm trying to do is get exact matches only:

```
[name, description].join(" ").downcase.scan(/apple|microsoft|google/)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: why is this tagged as 'scanf'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My regex skills are pretty weak, but I think you need to use a word boundary:

```
[name, description].join(" ").downcase.scan(/\b(apple|microsoft|google)\b/)
```

[Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/D2gm1vtTbu)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what information you want, but if you just want exact match, you do not need regex for the comparing part. Just compare the relevant strings.

```
splitted_strings = [name, description].join(" ").downcase.split(/\b/)

splitted_strings & %w[apple microsoft google]
# => the words that match given in the order of appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

Add proper boundaries entities in your regexp (`\b`). You can also use `#grep` method. instead of joining:

```
array.grep(your_regexp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question, and the situation I'd want to do those things, here's what I'd do for an actual program, where I had lists of sources, and their associated texts, and wanted to know the hits, I'd probably write something like this:

```
require 'pp'

names = ['From: Apple', 'From: Microsoft', 'From: Google.com']
descriptions = [
  '"an apple a day..."',
  'Microsoft Excel flight simulator... according to Microsoft',
  'Searches of Google revealed multiple hits for "google"'
]
targets = %w[apple microsoft google]
regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(targets).source })\b/i

names.zip(descriptions) do |n,d|
  name_hits, description_hits = [n, d].map{ |s| s.scan(regex) }
  pp [name_hits, description_hits]
end
```

Which outputs:

```
[["Apple"], ["apple"]]
[["Microsoft"], ["Microsoft", "Microsoft"]]
[["Google"], ["Google", "google"]]
```

This would let me know the letter-case of the words, so I could try to differentiate the apple fruit from Apple the company, and get word counts, helping to show relevance of the text.

The `regex` looks like:

```
/\b(?:apple|microsoft|google)\b/i
```

It's case insensitive but `scan` will returns words in their original case.

`names`, `descriptions` and `targets` could all come from a database or separate files, helping to separate the data from the code and the need to modify the code as the targets change.
I'd use a list of target words and use Regexp.union to quickly build the pattern.